# Get the anchor element on the same size as the parent div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I want the `outerDiv` to onclick open a new windows tab with a specific `href`. Every div is `display: flex`.

```
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div>
   <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to just place a `a (anchor)` element inside the `div` but it didnt work.
I cant get the `a` element on the same size as the parent div element.
Tried to set the height and width of the `a` to 100%, but didnt change anything.

```
<div class="outerDiv">
      <a href=...></a>
      <div>
       <img>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: <div class="outerDiv">
 <a href="xsxsx">
  <div>
 <img>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>     bind div inside anchor tag

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do/have. Please consider providing a [mcve] so that we could follow along.

Comment: put your code in a snippet including CSS code

Answer (score 0):

what I understand from your explanation is that you want the `outerDiv` to work as a button that opens a new page, and you want the `anchor` inside it to have the same `height` and `width` as its parent which is `outerDiv`.

Is that it?

if this is the case then you just need to set `outerDiv` `display` to `flex` then give the `link` `100% height and width`.

```css
.outerDiv {
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
}

.link {
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="outerDiv">
    <a class="link" href="#">link</a>
    <div>
     <img>
    </div>
  </div>
```

or just set the `anchor`'s `display` to `block` as @Farshad Vaghari suggested

```css
.outerDiv {
  /* display: flex; */
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
}

.link {
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="outerDiv">
    <a class="link" href="#">link</a>
    <div>
     <img>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change width and height of `a` tag, change display to block or inline-block because `a` tags are inline level by default:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
      <a style="display: block" href=...></a>
      <div>
       <img>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now set width = 100% and height = 100% to get the `a` element on the same size as the parent div element is.